# Can i build libdispatch on my xcode?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, libdispatch

I want to know how GCD work on iOS.Then I download **libdispatch-913.30.4** from opensource.apple.com, but i don't know how to build and debug it on my Xocde, it has much error.

the **install.md** says i can build it with above code:

```
sh autogen.sh
./configure
make
make install
```

but i get this error

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
```

so who can help me?

Comment: Are you running these commands in the same directory in which you installed the source code?

Comment: @DaltonSweeney yep, if not i can't sh autogen.sh